# Как сделать анимацию нажатия на объект в Unity, используя C#?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу игру с элементами кликера и мне нужно сделать эффект нажатия, например, чтобы иконка объекта, на который нужно нажимать, уменьшалась и потом, когда игрок отпустит палец, увеличивалась. Я пробовал сделать это через *transform*, но получалось только уменьшение и все. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум. *1 способ*: через компонент `Button` и анимацию. *2 способ*: через компонент `EventTrigger`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто подключите компонент `Button`, но не ставьте на него функции. Если надо цвета менять там в компоненте ставьте `Color Tint`, если меняйте спрайты ставьте `Sprite Swap` или если анимация есть собственная ставьте `Animation`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

как вариант
реализовать интерфейсы IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler

создать две анимации для уменьшения и для увеличения

добавить их в аниматор, добавить переход между ними по изменению булевого поля
и использовать animator.SetBool()

в IPointerDownHandler переключаете на увеличение
а в 
IPointerUpHandler на уменьшение

IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler эти интерфейсы позволят отследить нажатие и отпускание. В их реализацию стоит поместить логику выполнения переключения анимации. Что бы их подключить нужно добавить :

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
```

создаете анимацию для объекта.  Находите меню аниматора(Windows/Animation/Animator)

Вот ссылка по работе с аниматором 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/Animator.html
Эта статья и дальнейшие расписывают как создавать параметры и использовать их

Comment: забыл дописать, что я новичок)) понял половину вашего ответа, но все равно спасибо, задали нужный вектор, буду разбираться.

Comment: @dreamboy я расписал конкретнее.